# What's the difference between std::string::c_str and std::string::data?

Tags: c++, stdstring, c-str

Why would I ever want to call [`std::string::data()`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/data) over [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/c_str)? Surely there is some method to the standard's madness here...

Comment: Would just like to point out that in the next version of C++ [C++11 or C++0x or whatever you want to call it], the two functions are synonymous by definition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

c_str() guarantees NUL termination. data() does not.

Comment: I figured it would be something simple I'd overlooked - thanks!

Comment: In reality though, they probably point to the same thing (not that you should rely on it).

Comment: @Zifre: they may point to the same address, but after a mutating operation (str += "..." ), the implementation could leave the internal data buffer without the null termination, and only add the '\0' when the c_str() method is called.

Comment: Note that this is no longer true from C++11 on (data() is the same as c_str())

Answer (score 6):

c_str() return a pointer to the data with a NUL byte appended so you can use the return value as a "C string".

data() returns a pointer to the data without any modifications.

Use c_str() if the code you are using assumes a string is NUL terminated (such as any function written to handle C strings).

Answer (score 1):

Now in MS STL 10.0 there doesn't seem to be any difference, as I see this in the header:

...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring

```
const _Elem *c_str() const
    {   // return pointer to null-terminated nonmutable array
    return (_Myptr());
    }

const _Elem *data() const
    {   // return pointer to nonmutable array
    return (c_str());
    }
```

So they return the same thing.

Comment: It also looks like it's exactly the same in VC 9.0 too.

Comment: This is behavior that is allowed by the current standard, and required by the next one.  I suspect most libraries have been doing this for a while now, in preparation of the change over.