# Difference in comparing string .c_str() and normal string

Tags: c++

I wanted to know what the difference between the two codes is. When  I use .c_str() it does not work

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >::iterator it

for(;it!=MySet.end();++it)
{
        if(std::get<1>(*it).c_str()=="PAUSE")  //Why it works only with std::get<1>(*it) and not with std::get<1>(*it).c_str()
        {
            TempDefaultVan = std::get<0>(*it).c_str();
        }
}
```

Comment: With c_str() you're comparing the pointers to chars, not the actual sequence of characters.

Comment: `c_str()` returns a `const char *`, and pointer comparison is only "true" when the points point to the same memory location (which is *not* what you want). You want to compare the contents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534399/whats-the-difference-between-stdstringc-str-and-stdstringdata
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194634/string-c-str-vs-data

Comment: @ferozakbar this has nothing to do with `data`, but pointer comparison vs. string contents comparision.

Comment: `strcmp` for string pointer (`const char*`) comparison.

Comment: @Borgleader can you put that as the answer

Comment: @MistyD you don't need to use `strcmp`, just get rid of the `.c_str()` and let `std::string::operator==` do its job. Like you say, *it works*.

Comment: I understand that. I was-just curious why the actual thing wasn't working.I just got rid of c_str() and it works. I just wanted to know the reason and now I know. Waiting for an answer to close this

Comment: @MistyD Put it below in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::get<1>(*it)` returns an object of type std::string. This class has overload `operator ==` to compare objects of type std::string with character arrays.

`std::get<1>(*it).c_str()` returns a character array. Arrays have no the comparison operator. To compare character arrays you should use standard C function `std::strcmp`

So you could write

```
if( std::strcmp( std::get<1>(*it).c_str(), "PAUSE" ) == 0 )
```

If you will write simply as

```
if(std::get<1>(*it).c_str()=="PAUSE")
```

then the compiler will compare two pointers because it converts arrays to pointers to their first elements in such expressions. And as the result this expression will be equal always to false if the arrays occupy different areas of memory.

Comment: `strcpy` isn't right.. shouldn't it be one of: `strcmp`, `stricmp`, `strcasecmp`.

Comment: Also, if you have a `std::string`, why even bother with `strcmp`?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames There is no such functions as stricmp and strcasecmp in the C++ Standard. They are non-standard functions.

Comment: @crashmstr I agree. It can be used if a function does not accept an object of type std::string as an argument.

Comment: I agree that `stricmp` is microsoft's implementation of non-standard `strcasecmp` but you're using `strcpy`. You should use `strcmp` which is standard. I was just listing the possibilities of `const char*` comparison. Btw, I didn't downvote. Just letting you know that you might want to edit the example you gave.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I have not understood why I should not use std::strcmp.

Comment: No no. I am saying you SHOULD use `strcmp`. Atm you have: `if( std::strcpy(....`  <-- notice the `strcpy`?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames  It was a typo.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Because you're obtaining a C-string for no reason. Use the member functions that `std::string` provides for you.

Answer (score 4):

So basically what is happening is `.c_str()` is returning a `const char*`. This will cause `operator ==` to compare pointers and not the string's content. Since both of these are clearly not pointing to the same memory location (since `"PAUSE"` is a string literal), this will always be false.

Comment: -1: `c_str()` does not return a `char*`. You also have some grammatical errors in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
std::get<1>(*it).c_str()=="PAUSE"
```

is comparing two `const char *`, which both point to strings. This is not what you usually want when comparing strings, as it will only evaluate to true when they point to the same place in memory.

This code:

```
std::get<1>(*it)=="PAUSE"
```

Will use `std::string::operator==` to compare the contents of the `std::string` `std::get<1>(*it)` with the contents of `"PAUSE"`. If you instead had two `char *` values, you could use `strcmp`, but since you have a `std::string`, this is the best way to make the comparison (and, as you say, "it works").